# Which is the correct way to create an apk file

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner at android programming so I might not know how to do things correctly but I have a question about creating an apk file. What is the difference when you do a Build APK and Generate Signed APK in `Android Studio`? Will the program be different?

Comment: No. But it will be signed for publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Developer docs page for [Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) really explains it all, but just to answer your particular question:

Build APK will build an APK with your current configuration (AKA Build Variant) using the debug keystore. Generate a signed APK will allow you to use your own keystore (and facilitate you creating one if you need to) to sign your app. You'll need to do this to upload to the Google Play store for example.

You can change the active build variant for any module (e.g. the app module if you app is small and simple) in the Build Variant menu, which by default is on the bottom left side of the Android Studio screen. You can edit them in the project settings, or jump there from the Build > Edit Build Types... menu

The default build configuration (AKA Build Variants) for Build APK will be debug, whereas you'll generally use a release config for Generate Signed APK. Depending on how these configurations differ, the program will differ. For example you might only enable analytics for a release build, which is set by some flag in your Gradle build file.

Answer (score 1):

It won't change the behaviour of the application. Signing an apk attaches a public key certificate to it. If you're not planning on distributing the app then don't worry about signing it.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

**Build APK**

- Unknown source must be checked in settings for installing this apk
- You can't upload it to playstore for publishing

**Signed apk**

- You need to create certificate file to create Signed Apk , certificate contains the address of the organisation and password for feature version update
- can be uploaded to playstore for publishing